# QR decomposition of a matrix and eigenvectors

Tags: c, matrix, algebra, triangular

perhaps this is more a question of theory than programming, but I can't find an acceptable answer. I wrote this code in C++, which tridiagonalizes the symmetric matrix A with the function HouseholderMain (which overwrites A and updates PP with the matrix that tridiagonalizes A), then finds the QR decomposition of A with the function QRtridiag (which overwrites A with its upper triangular form and gives the matrix Q of the decomposition) and finally calculates the vector of eigenvalues a and the matrix of eigenvectors X of the upper triangular matrix A with the function AutovTriang.

```
int main()
{
    int n = 4;
    double** A = createMatrix(n, n);
    double** PP = createMatrix(n, n);
    double** Q = createMatrix(n, n);
    double** X = createMatrix(n, n);
    double* a = createVector(n);

    A[0][0] = 1;
    A[0][1] = A[1][0] = 2;
    A[0][2] = A[2][0] = -3;
    A[0][3] = A[3][0] = 4;
    A[1][1] = 1;
    A[1][2] = A[2][1] = -1;
    A[1][3] = A[3][1] = 9;
    A[2][2] = 2;
    A[2][3] = A[3][2] = 10;
    A[3][3] = 0;

    HouseholderMain(A, PP, n);
    QRtridiag(A, Q, n);
    AutovTriang(A, X, a, n);

        return 0;
}

void HouseholderMain(double** A, double** PP, int n)
{
    int i, j, k, l;
    double sum;
    double** P = createMatrix(n, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            PP[i][j] = (i == j ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }
    for (int l = 0; l < n - 2; l++) {
        Householder2Cycle(A, P, n, l);
        double** PA = multMatrices(P, A, n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                sum = 0;
                for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    sum += PA[i][k] * P[k][j];
                }
                A[i][j] = sum;
            }
        }
        double** a = multMatrices(PP, P, n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                PP[i][j] = a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}


void Householder2Cycle(double** A, double** P, int n, int k)
{
    int i, j;
    double sum, mod, mod2x, h;
    double* x = createVector(n);
    for (i = 0; i < k + 1; i++) {
        x[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = k + 2; i < n; i++) {
        x[i] = A[i][k];
    }
    sum = 0;
    for (i = k + 1; i < n; i++) {
        sum += A[i][k] * A[i][k];
    }
    mod = (A[k+1][k] > 0 ? sqrt(sum) : -sqrt(sum));
    x[k + 1] = A[k + 1][k] + mod;
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += x[i] * x[i];
    }
    mod2x = sum;
    h = mod2x / 2;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            P[i][j] = (i == j ? 1 : 0) - x[i] * x[j] / h;
        }
    }
    freeVector(x);
}


void QRtridiag(double** A, double** Q, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    double theta, c, s, t, p, pp;
    for (j = 0; j <= n - 2; j++) {
        for (i = j + 1; i < n; i++) {
            Q[i][j] = Q[j][i] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Q[i][i] = 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        theta = A[i][i] / A[i+1][i];
        t = 1 / (fabs(theta) + sqrt(theta * theta + 1));
        if (theta < 0) t = -t;
        c = (1 - t * t) / (1 + t * t);
        s = 2 * t / (1 + t * t);
        p = A[i][i + 1];
        A[i][i] = c * A[i][i] + s * A[i + 1][i];
        A[i + 1][i] = 0;
        if (i < n - 2) {
            A[i][i + 2] = s * A[i + 1][i + 2];
            A[i + 1][i + 2] = c * A[i + 1][i + 2];
        }
        A[i][i + 1] = c * p + s * A[i + 1][i + 1];
        A[i + 1][i + 1] = -s * p + c * A[i + 1][i + 1];
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            pp = Q[j][i];
            Q[j][i] = c * pp;
            Q[j][i+1] = -s * pp;
        }
        Q[i+1][i] = s;
        Q[i + 1][i + 1] = c;
    }
}


void AutovTriang(double** A, double** X, double* a, int n)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = A[i][i];
    }
    for (k = n - 1; k >= 2; k--) {
        X[k][k] = 1;
        X[k - 1][k] = -A[k - 1][k] / (a[k - 1] - a[k]);
        for (i = k - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            X[i][k] = (-A[i][i + 1] * X[i + 1][k] - A[i][i + 2] * X[i + 2][k]) / (a[i] - a[k]);
        }
    }
    X[1][1] = X[0][0] = 1;
    X[0][1] = -A[0][1] / (a[0] - a[1]);
    for (j = 0; j <= n - 2; j++) {
        for (i = j + 1; i < n; i++) {
            X[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is simply the following: how can I relate eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the final upper triangular matrix to those of the original matrix? I tried to understand the QR algorithm but I am not sure it offers what I need. I have the eigensystem of the triangular matrix yet and I think there is an easy way to calculate the eigensystem of the original matrix using the matrices PP and Q, but I cannot figure out how to do it.
Can someone help me? Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

A direct relation is that the product of the diagonal elements of R (which are the eignvalues of R) times the determinant of Q (which is +1 or -1), from the QR decomposition, is equal to the product of the eigenvalues of your original A.

There are iterative procedures to get the eigenvalues of QR with repeated applications of the QR decomposition. Those procedures are sped up by the tri-diagonalization you have already done. The eigenvalues of your original A are equal to the eigenvalues of its tridiagonalization, and you can back-convert the eigenvectors using the transformation matrix you accumulated in `PP`. If we call A' the tridiagonal form of A, then A' = PP<sup>T</sup> A PP, so A = PP A' PP<sup>T</sup>, where that transformation would convert the eigenvectors of A' to A.

The simplest procedure to get the eigenvalues of A' is to get its QR decomposition, and compute RQ. Do a QR decomposition on that for a new Q and R, compute RQ again, until the diagonals of successive RQ's have sufficiently converged. The sequence of RQ's will approach diagonal, with the eigenvalues of A or A' on the diagonal.

This can take many iterations. A way to significantly speed up the convergence is by subtracting a constant from the diagonal elements of QR, and then adding that constant back to RQ. Choosing the minimum absolute value of the diagonal elements of QR as the constant works well. In a test I tried, that reduced the iterations from 547 to 32.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I completed the code with the QR algorithm yet and improved the previous code a little. I will try to implement the subtraction technique you suggested.

Comment: I would recommend not allocating matrices all the time. You should allocate some work areas once, and keep reusing those until you're done. For example, your matrix multiply should take three three matrices instead of two, multiplying two of them and putting the result in the other one. Then your Householder main loop could be something like: `Householder2Cycle(A, P, n, l); mult(T, P, A, n); mult(A, T, P, n); mult(T, PP, P, n); copy(PP, T, n);`, where `P` and `T` are pre-allocated matrix work areas.

Comment: I improved the matrix multiplications too and the structure of the code in general. I'll report it in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I write the full code with little improvements in the following. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
int main() 
{
    int n = 4;
    double** A = createMatrix(n, n);
    A[0][0] = 3.69583037;
    A[0][1] = A[1][0] = 0.57095943;
    A[0][2] = A[2][0] = 1.25982728;
    A[0][3] = A[3][0] = -0.91138766;
    A[1][1] = -5.72767862;
    A[1][2] = A[2][1] = 1.40997728;
    A[1][3] = A[3][1] = 3.09590731;
    A[2][2] = 0.84352098;
    A[2][3] = A[3][2] = -0.00810195;
    A[3][3] = 2.71813063;

    double** eigenvec = createMatrix(n, n);
    double* eigenval = createVector(n);

    HouseholderAlgorithm(A, eigenvec, eigenval, n);

    return 0;
}


void Tridiag(double** A, double** P, int n, int k)
/*  Tridiagonalizes a real symmetric nxn matrix A using the Householder algorithm if called repeatedly
    for k = 0, ... , n - 3.  P (passed as any nxn matrix) is the matrix acting the transformation.  */
{
    int i, j, m;
    double sum, mod, h;
    double* x = createVector(n);
    double* y = createVector(n);
    for (i = 0; i < k + 1; i++) {
        x[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = k + 2; i < n; i++) {
        x[i] = A[i][k];
    }
    sum = 0;
    for (i = k + 1; i < n; i++) {
        sum += A[i][k] * A[i][k];
    }
    mod = (A[k + 1][k] > 0 ? sqrt(sum) : -sqrt(sum));
    x[k + 1] = A[k + 1][k] + mod;
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += x[i] * x[i];
    }
    h = sum / 2;
    for (i = k + 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = k + 1; j < n; j++) {
            y[j] = A[j][i];
        }
        for (j = k + 1; j < n; j++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (m = k + 1; m < n; m++) {
                sum += ((j == m ? 1 : 0) - x[j] * x[m] / h) * y[m];
            }
            A[j][i] = sum;
        }
    }
    for (i = k + 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = k + 1; j < n; j++) {
            y[j] = A[i][j];
        }
        for (j = k + 1; j < n; j++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (m = k + 1; m < n; m++) {
                sum += y[m] * ((j == m ? 1 : 0) - x[m] * x[j] / h);
            }
            A[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    A[k + 1][k] = A[k][k + 1] = -mod;
    for (i = k + 2; i < n; i++) {
        A[i][k] = A[k][i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = k; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = k + 1; j < n; j++) {
            y[j] = P[i][j];
        }
        for (j = k + 1; j < n; j++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (m = k + 1; m < n; m++) {
                sum += y[m] * ((j == m ? 1 : 0) - x[m] * x[j] / h);
            }
            P[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    freeVector(x);
    freeVector(y);
}



void QRdecom(double** A, double** Q, double** P, int n)
/*  Gives the QR decomposition of a real symmetric matrix A. On output overwrites
    A with the upper triangular matrix R. Q (passed as the unit nxn matrix) is overwritten with the
    unitary matrix of the decomposition. On each call multiply the matrices P and Q and overwrites
    P with the result.  */
{
    int i, j;
    double theta, c, s, t, p, pp;
    for (i = 0; i <= n - 2; i++) {
        theta = A[i][i] / A[i + 1][i];
        t = 1 / (fabs(theta) + sqrt(theta * theta + 1));
        if (theta < 0) t = -t;
        c = (1 - t * t) / (1 + t * t);
        s = 2 * t / (1 + t * t);
        p = A[i][i + 1];
        A[i][i] = c * A[i][i] + s * A[i + 1][i];
        A[i + 1][i] = 0;
        if (i < n - 2) {
            A[i][i + 2] = s * A[i + 1][i + 2];
            A[i + 1][i + 2] = c * A[i + 1][i + 2];
        }
        A[i][i + 1] = c * p + s * A[i + 1][i + 1];
        A[i + 1][i + 1] = -s * p + c * A[i + 1][i + 1];
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            pp = Q[j][i];
            Q[j][i] = c * pp;
            Q[j][i + 1] = -s * pp;
        }
        Q[i + 1][i] = s;
        Q[i + 1][i + 1] = c;
        for (j = 0; j <= n - 1; j++) {
            pp = P[j][i];
            P[j][i] = c * pp + s * P[j][i + 1];
            P[j][i + 1] = -s * pp + c * P[j][i + 1];
        }
    }
}


void QRinv(double** A, double** Q, int n)
/*  Takes the matrices Q and R (which is A on input) of the QR decomposition and 
    gives the inverse decomposition RQ overwriting A with the result.  */
{
    int j, k;
    double q, qq, qqq;
    for (j = 1; j <= n - 3; j++) {
        q = A[j][j];
        qq = A[j][j + 1];
        qqq = A[j][j + 2];
        A[j][j - 1] = q * Q[j][j - 1];
        A[j][j] = q * Q[j][j] + qq * Q[j + 1][j];
        A[j][j + 1] = q * Q[j][j + 1] + qq * Q[j + 1][j + 1] + qqq * Q[j + 2][j + 1];
    }
    q = A[0][0];
    qq = A[0][1];
    qqq = A[0][2];
    A[0][0] = q * Q[0][0] + qq * Q[1][0];
    A[0][1] = q * Q[0][1] + qq * Q[1][1] + qqq * Q[2][1];
    q = A[n - 2][n - 2];
    qq = A[n - 2][n - 1];
    A[n - 2][n - 3] = q * Q[n - 2][n - 3];
    A[n - 2][n - 2] = q * Q[n - 2][n - 2] + qq * Q[n - 1][n - 2];
    A[n - 2][n - 1] = q * Q[n - 2][n - 1] + qq * Q[n - 1][n - 1];
    q = A[n - 1][n - 1];
    A[n - 1][n - 2] = q * Q[n - 1][n - 2];
    A[n - 1][n - 1] = q * Q[n - 1][n - 1];
    for (j = 2; j < n; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < j - 1; k++) {
            A[j][k] = A[k][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}


void QRdiag(double** A, double** P, int n)
/*  Diagonalizes a real symmetric tridiagonal matrix A (overwritten in output) with the QR algorithm.
    P (any nxn matrix can be passed) is the matrix performing the transformation,
    its column being the eigenvectors of the original matrix */
{
    int i, j, k;
    double** Q = createMatrix(n, n);
    for (k = 0; k < 30; k++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= n - 2; j++) {
            for (i = j + 1; i < n; i++) {
                Q[i][j] = Q[j][i] = 0;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Q[i][i] = 1;
        }
        QRdecom(A, Q, P, n);
        QRinv(A, Q, n);
    }
    freeMatrix(Q, n);
}



void HouseholderAlgorithm(double** A, double** P, double* a, int n)
/*  Diagonalizes a real symmetric matrix A (overwritten on output) with the QR algorithm.
    P (passed as any nxn matrix) is the matrix of eigenvectors and a is the vector of eigenvalues. */
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            P[i][j] = (i == j ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) {
        Tridiag(A, P, n, i);
    }
    QRdiag(A, P, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = A[i][i];
    }
}

double** createMatrix(int r, int c)
{
    double** matrix = (double**)malloc(r * sizeof(double*));
    if (matrix) {
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            matrix[i] = (double*)malloc(c * sizeof(double));
            if (matrix[i]) {}
            else {
                printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
                free(matrix[i]);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
        free(matrix);
        exit(0);
    }
    return matrix;
}

void freeMatrix(double** a, int r)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            free(a[i]);
        }
        free(a);
}
```

Comment: Though you did not provide the complete implementation, the fact that `freeMatrix()` needs a second argument suggests that your `createMatrix()` is not optimal. The space for the entire matrix should be obtained with a single `malloc()`, so that the rows are adjacent in memory. That will make better use of the cache, speeding up the operations. A side effect is that you then just need two `free()`'s to release the memory for the matrix, and don't need `n`.

Comment: I don't know if I've understood what you mean. I've added the functions createMatrix and freeMatrix in the bottom of the code.

Comment: What I mean is don't do r+1 `malloc()`'s. Do two `malloc()`'s. Just two.

Comment: `double **createMatrix(int r, int c) {
    double **A = malloc(r * sizeof(double *));
    double *p = malloc(r * (c * sizeof(double)));
    assert(p != NULL && A != NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++, p += c)
        A[i] = p;
    return A;
}`

Comment: `void freeMatrix(double **A) {
    free(A[0]);
    free(A);
}`